# CakePHP 3 : create ul/ol list

Tags: cakephp, html-lists, cakephp-3.0

I am working on CakePHP 3.

I have to create `ul` list like this

```
<ul class="slides"
  <li data-thumb="image.jpg">
    <img src="image.jpg">
  </li>
  <li data-thumb="image.jpg">
    <img src="image.jpg">
  </li>
</ul>
```

In CakePHP Book in `Html Helper` [HERE](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#creating-nested-lists), it has an example to create nested list and use it multiple times. But I want to create list for only one time use.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the paths to the images being wrong, if the html is not going to change code very similar to this in a template is completely fine:

```
<ul class="slides"
  <li data-thumb="/images/image.jpg">
    <img src="/images/image.jpg">
  </li>
  <li data-thumb="/images/image.jpg">
    <img src="/images/image.jpg">
  </li>
</ul>
```

It is a good idea however, to use [appropriate](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/url.html) [helpers](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#linking-to-images), so that the paths are correct irrespective of how the application is installed (i.e. `http://localhost/project-name/` or `http://my-project.dev/` or `http://example.com/` or etc.):

```
<ul class="slides"
  <li data-thumb="<?= $this->Url->image('image.jpg') ?>">
    <?= $this->Html->image('image.jpg') ?>
  </li>
  <li data-thumb="<?= $this->Url->image('image.jpg') ?>">
    <?= $this->Html->image('image.jpg') ?>
  </li>
</ul>
```